# How to convert this sql to Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

i have the sql below that i would like to convert to C# using linq. Can someone tell me how this best can be done with linq?

```
select A.field1, A.Field2, A.Field4,  A.Field5,  A.Field4 ,A.Field6
from MPhoneParts A

where A.Field3= 'Batteri' AND NOT EXIST(

select * from MPhoneParts B where 

B.Field3='cover'
A.Field2= B.Field2 AND 
A.Field4= B.Field4 AND
B.Field6='Production354')
```

Cheers
Mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be a better approach (quite possibly using a join...), but:

```
var query = from a in db.MPhoneParts
            where a.Field3 == "Batteri" &&
                  !db.MPhoneParts.Any(b => b.Field3 == "cover" &&
                                           a.Field2 == b.Field2 &&
                                           a.Field4 == b.Field4 &&
                                           b.Field6 == "Production354")
            select a;
```

Comment: The tables are both most likely `db.MPhoneParts`; the `A` and `B` in the query shown are just the aliases

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is mistyped and you meant to check for the `NOT IN` clause.

here is the solution on how to write the `NOT IN`... in linq, hope this helps:

[The NOT IN clause in LINQ to SQL](http://programminglinq.com/blogs/marcorusso/archive/2008/01/14/the-not-in-clause-in-linq-to-sql.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
var qry =
    from a in db.PhoneParts
    where a.Field3 == "Batteri"
    && !db.PhoneParts.Any(b =>
             b.Field3 == "cover"
          && b.Field6 == "Production354"
          && b.Field2 == a.Field2
          && b.Field4 == a.Field4)
    select new { a.Field1, a.Field2, a.Field4, a.Field5, a.Field6 };
```

But thoughts:

- `Field1` thru `Field6` are *horrible* names
- you can use the existing SQL via `db.ExecuteQuery`

Comment: yes, i did not want to expose my actual database fields but many thanks